# Can't split using Ionic pipes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I can't `split` the value using Ionic `pipe`.

```
<div class="col" style="text-align: right">{{ timearrivals | mattDamon }}</div>
```

The `pipe` code is here:

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'mattDamon'
})
export class MattDamon {
    transform(value, args) {
        let time = value.split('T')[1];
        let timehr = time.split(':')[0];
        let timemin = time.split(':')[1];
        let Fulltim = timehr + ":" + timemin;
        return Fulltim;
    }
}
```

It shows the following error:

[image]

But I `split` another variable using this `pipe` in another page.

```
<P>{{ item.operationalTimes.publishedArrival.dateLocal | mattDamon }}</P>
```

Comment: it shows undefined

Comment: why i get undefined? 
when is using like this {{timearrivals}} it shows the value
but  {{timearrivals | mattDamon}} it shows undefined

Comment: why i get undefined? when is using like this {{timearrivals}} it shows the value but {{timearrivals | mattDamon}} it shows undefined

Comment: @robbannn tnx budy for helping me. it working <3 <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `timearrivals` does not yet have a value the first time the `mattDamon`-pipe is run. To protect yourself from trying to call `split()` on `timearrivals` when it is `undefined`, use a simple `if-else`:

```js
transform(value, args){
    if(value){
        let time = value.split('T')[1];
        let timehr = time.split(':')[0];
        let timemin = time.split(':')[1];

        let Fulltim = timehr + ":" + timemin;
        return Fulltim;
    }
    else{
        return value;
    }
}
```